# Как добавить фон на сайте?

Tags: python, django

Как добавить фон на сайте? Использую фреймворк `Django`.
Вот пишу я в `detail.html`:

```css
body{background-image:url("Путь к картинке"):
```

и ничего не получается. Потом следовал правилам как поставить фон, там надо было создать `index.html` по пути `Мое приложение/templates/Мое приложение/index.html` и создать `style.css` по пути `Мое приложение/static/Мое приложение/style.css` и создать папку `images` в которой надо было хранить фотки для сайта.
Вообщем я не понимаю как поставить картинку на фон, просто изображение под тегом `<img>` спокойно добавлялось (только надо было написать `{% load static %}`).
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Я уже писал это,не получалось

Answer (score 1):

**Подключи CSS файл . И напиши следующее**

```
body{
background-image: url(путь к картинке)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPD:
В css файлах, в таком случае, позволяет поставить на фон изображение, что храниться в `/media/`.

```css
background-image: url("/media/images/projects/hookadoo.PNG"); /*фон установился*/
```

---

В `settings.py` пропиши:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

В `urls.py`:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # твой urlpatterns,
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

В шаблоне:

```
{% load static %} {# После {% extends ... %} если используется #}
```

Теперь в шаблоне обращайся к статике так `{% static 'путь к твоей статике' %}`.
Например, статика моего приложения лежит по такому пути `D:\coding\my-site\polls\static\polls\plugins\jquery-1.11.3.min.js`. Тогда её вызов будет следующим:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/plugins/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Так же перед запуском (в том числе в продакшене) используй `python manage.py collectstatic`.

[Пример моего сайта-резюме.](https://github.com/vladrunk/ResumeProject)
Так же возможно будет полезной [эта инструкция](https://github.com/vladrunk/howTo/wiki/Deploy-on-VPS). Писал для себя по ходу дела.

Comment: Добрый день. 
Проверьте, пожалуйста, ответ.